# What happens if you feed power into a wall outlet during a blackout?

Tags: electrical

My community is running some preparedness/awareness regarding "blackout" power outages. So we're talking about multi-day outages, not intermittent minute- or hours-long outages. There was one idea that I wanted to raise here because I find it interesting.
<sup>This is purely speculation; I do not have this equipment and I do not intend to try it out.</sup>

- Say we have a normal house in Europe, normal breaker system, and it's not getting any power from outside due to a blackout event.
- Say we have a diesel/petrol-powered generator that outputs 230V with a delivery capacity of a few thousand Watts.
- Say we have a [suicide cable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suicide_cable) and connect it from the generator to any wall outlet in the house.

Questions:

1. Would the power be available in the entire house?
2. Would the power only reach to the breaker, and not go to other parts of the house?
3. Would the power be routed through all breakers and also back out to the street and to the larger power grid?
4. Could the house be powered, if the master breaker is thrown and every section breaker remains hot?
5. Is this a very stupid question because that's a common thing to do in some parts of the world?
6. Is this a very stupid thing to do because "obviously" it would not work? Why (not)?

---

**Update:** How can I not add this?

[image]

Comment: There is no « normal » european system: France is different to Switzerland, Switzerland different to Germany, Uk different to Spain etc etc

Comment: Trying to backfeed like that is not a goid idea on any level.

Comment: If the few thousand watts is more than the circuit/outlet is made for it can burn down the house.  Guess a regular circuit of 13 amps by 230 volts can only take 2990 watts, if generator is less okay for not burning down.  The main thing is that the power also goes outside into power lines that power workers think are dead, killing power workers is not good.

Comment: There are a few safer ways to connect a generator to power a part or the whole house(if generator big enough) than what you are thinking.  Can google to find the safe ways or even search on here about connecting a generator to a house.

Comment: Isolator switch or "interlock is basically a device that disconnects the power from the street, so you are not sending your generator power back to the street.

Comment: **preparedness/awareness regarding "blackout" power outages** what is the purpose other than everyone running to buy a generator

Comment: **DON'T DO THIS!!**  The risk of electrocution is quite high, if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I don't think they named it a "suicide cord" on accident. You should try less hard to conceive a plan which uses a suicide cord. Anyways, there are already established ways of properly wiring a generator into a home so you should have started there. Assuming you don't cut your life short with a suicide cord then you'll be back-feeding the grid and supplying errant power to your neighbors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

##### TL;DR DON'T DO THIS AS DESCRIBED!

> 1. Would the power be available in the entire house?

Yes. Except limited by the branch circuit breaker. Which actually is the case even with a proper inlet and interlock, but more of a problem here because once you are using a suicide cord you might also be messing around with connectors. I'm not sure of the European equivalent, but in the US it might be connecting a 50A 240V outlet on the generator to a 240V 30A outlet in the house (e.g., clothes dryer), or even worse connecting *half* of a 30A outlet on the generator to a 15A outlet (e.g., "ordinary 120V receptacle") because once people get stupid, they move quickly to [Darwin territory](https://darwinawards.com/). Breakers don't trip immediately except in extreme circumstances (e.g., 2x or more of the rated current) but mild deliberate overloads are not a good thing.

> 2. Would the power only reach to the breaker, and not go to other parts of the house?

No.

> 3. Would the power be routed through all breakers and also back out to the street and to the larger power grid?

Yes! Which is extremely dangerous!

> 4. Could the house be powered, if the master breaker is thrown and every section breaker remains hot?

Yes. Which would be great. The problem is making sure the master breaker is thrown.

> 5. Is this a very stupid question because that's a common thing to do in some parts of the world?

It is **NOT** a stupid question. It is a great question because by asking the question you can find out how to do this safely.

> 6. Is this a very stupid thing to do because "obviously" it would not work? Why (not)?

It is a stupid thing because it can kill people. Seriously.

---

There are three main issues, both of which can be solved with a little bit of extra equipment.

The first, as already noted above, is that you can kill the people working on restoring your power. The solution is to **always** have the main breaker off when you are running on a generator. The way to do that is an **interlock**. An interlock is typically just a specially shaped piece of metal that is installed in a way that either the main breaker can be on (utility power) or one particular breaker next to it can be on (generator power) but never both at the same time. It prevents backfeed of the generator power into the utility lines. Really simple solution. But there is one more piece, an **inlet**, to solve two more problems.

The second problem is that suicide cords are dangerous **for the users**. If you plug in a suicide cord to a generator and a receptacle, shut off the main breaker and turn on the generator, you have safely powered your house. However, the suicide cord is inherently dangerous because *in normal use* it can present hot power on easily touched metal prongs in the plug. For example, if you turn on the generator and plug the cord into the generator before plugging the cord into the outlet (receptacle is the usual proper term, but outlet is a very specific term relevant here) then the prongs on the plug are **hot** and accidentally brushing against them will zap you, possibly fatally. There are other scenarios when you turn the generator off and the main power back on, etc. Suicide cords get their name for a reason. Using an **inlet** instead of an outlet solves this problem. An inlet has prongs instead of holes. You don't need a suicide cord because a regular cord (prongs on one end into the generator, holes on the other end into the inlet) works fine and works *safely*.

The third problem is carbon monoxide. (And other nasty gases, but CO is the worst in many ways.) The solution to that is to have the inlet **outside**. Which means you should not simply replace an unneeded outlet with an inlet - that would (usually) be inside which means either running the generator inside (never a good idea) or running it outside with an extension cord through a window or door (which can also let CO get inside).

To summarize:

- The concept of "generator powers one circuit which in turn powers the house" is 100% valid.
- To make it safe for the utility crews, you *must* have an interlock to prevent backfeed into the utility power.
- To make it safe for yourself, you *must* install an inlet (instead of an outlet) as the only item on the interlocked breaker, and install it outside to prevent CO from getting inside.

---

Example of an interlock - [Eaton CH, image from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-CH-PON-Mechanical-Interlock-Kits-CHPMIKCSR/314057112#overlay):

[image: Interlock kit]

Same model installed (my house):

[image: Eaton CH panel with interlock]

Note that interlocks are *relatively* expensive for what amounts to one or two pieces of sheet metal and a few screws. But each panel type has a specific interlock, and the vast majority of installations don't have an interlock (because they don't have a generator or other alternate power supply) so they are produced in very low quantities compared to the panels themselves. Don't let the extra $50 - $100 stop you from getting an interlock - it is a drop in the bucket compared to the generator and absolutely vital to safety.

Answer (score 7):

Adding one small point to multiple answers above: I don't think "interlocks" in the North American style are used in Europe.   Instead there is a single DIN-rail mounted device that performs the same function.  In the UK it's called a [changeover switch](https://tewltd.co.uk/product/esr-125a-240v-changeover-switch-eco125/).

[image]

The link is to a random example I googled.  In Austria I expect you'll find something similar that is suitable for your home.   You need lots of extra space in your ?Consumer Unit? (sorry, another UK term) and you need to run proper wiring from an outdoor generator inlet to there, not a suicide cord or any kind of cord.

The rail-mounted changeover switch is a little more elegant and not more expensive than an American interlock.

Comment: *not a suicide cord or any kind of cord* Correct. But there will still be a *cord* from the generator to the inlet, and *that* cord has to be a regular cord, *not* a suicide cord.

Comment: An alternative to that style of switch is a large rotary switch.  These often have a centre OFF position.

Answer (score 4):

> So we're talking about multi-day outages, not intermittent minute- or hours-long outages. There was one idea that I wanted to raise here because I find it interesting.

Anyone who suggests this should be educated with all deliberate speed.  The problem is not using a generator, but the manner of connection. This method is cheap, but so is the safe and legal method.   Especially in Europe where you only have one phase to mess with and less neutral complications, because your breakers interrupt neutral.

> Say we have a suicide cable and connect it from the generator to any wall outlet in the house.

The problem with a suicide cord is it defeats plug design **by making the exposed pointy things energized**. Even if you connect it exactly to procedure, someone might unplug it, placing the room in total darkness!

...And they are holding an energized plug in their hand. Or about to step on it. Because they can't see.

Such connections are made with a 2-step strategy.  A normal extension cord is used going to an **inlet** (wall socket with pointy things instead of holes). Second, the inlet is *interlocked* so it can't be energized unless all other sources are off.  *For this discussion, solar which is "Grid Interactive" (UL 1741 / IEC 62109) does not count as a "power source"*.

> 1. Would the power be available in the entire house?

*Maybe*.  First if you have 3-phase from the utility, it would only power that 1 phase. *A properly installed inlet/interlock would address this*.

Second, I have concerns over whether the RCD would stop this current.  It might, which would be nice... or it might not.

> 2. Would the power only reach to the breaker, and not go to other parts of the house?

It would stop at the breaker **if it trips** the breaker. Connect a 30A generator to a 13A circuit, and cheerfully run loads all over the house, that 13A breaker is going to trip. *At that point, you could power 30A of stuff within that circuit, setting the wires on fire*.

> 3. Would the power be routed through all breakers and also back out to the street and to the larger power grid?

Well, that's the worry! Transformers are bidirectional. If you feed 230V to the low side of a 230V/9600V transformer, you get 9600V out the other side - a rude surprise to linemen who haven't slept for 40 hours as they try to restore power after a regional ice storm, hurricane etc.

**But maybe**.  The wildcard here is Europe's use of "whole house RCD". (or RCBO, which is a combo regular breaker + RCD). An RCD guards the whole house or large parts of a house.  I don't know how European DIN-Rail-mount RCDs are built, so I can't say for sure what would happen, but I might guess they would interact with European earthing in a funny way.  Here's what European ["earthing"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE) looks like in the **TN-C-S** system.

[image]

Now some houses have **TN-S**, which is the same exact thing but with the "earth" wire extended all the way to the pole transformer.

A/C is rare, services are small (typically 32-64A single-phase, so 1/6 to 1/3 of an American 200A/240V)... and transformers are more powerful (they are making 400V 3-phase), so single transformers cover many more homes.  Thus that earth spike may be fairly distant.

So, you have a portable generator.  It already has neutral and earth bonded on the generator (to help its onboard RCD work).  The loads in your house are going to have 2 ways to get neutral.  #1 straight from the generator neutral to the house neutral.  #2 via the neutral-earth bond on the generator, over the earth wire **to the PEN or to the transformer**, then back on the utility neutral and through the RCD.

Current flows on ALL paths in proportion to its **conductance** (1/resistance).  Therefore a fraction of neutral current (certainly more than 30mA) will flow through the RCD. That will trip it if it's energized. RCD cuts line and neutral, so you are fully isolated. Assuming that your RCD is capable of reverse current; American ones are not.

So this creates an interesting wrinkle to the old "backfeed the utility and shock a lineman to death" problem.  The RCD might be the automatic protection linemen need; or not.

On the other hand, if the generator *did not* have its neutral-earth bonded, or if the suicide cord did not carry earth or it's broken in the cord, then the RCD will not see any current, will not trip, and likely will backfeed the grid.

Still, the right answer is an interlock.  That is necessary when using a proper inlet; if we relied on the RCD'd characteristics and didn't bother with an interlock, the inlet prongs would be live.

> 4. Could the house be powered, if the master breaker is thrown and every section breaker remains hot?

Yes, except it will be blocked by two things.

- RCDs, as discussed above. Larger houses use 2 or more RCDs each protecting some of the circuits in the house. That's because wiring and random non-failing appliances do have tiny amounts of leakage; all the stuff in a large house may sum to >30mA sometimes, causing nuisance trips when really nothing is wrong.
- Multiple phases. Often instead of giving you 200A@230V like Americans, they provide 63A 3-phase (which is about the same thing). You would be backfeeding only one phase, so only things on that phase could work. *This is easily resolved when designing a properly interlocked system*.

> 5. Is this a very stupid question because that's a common thing to do in some parts of the world?

No. It is a very *common* question because that's a *stupid* thing to do in *every* part of the world.

> 6. Is this a very stupid thing to do because "obviously" it would not work? Why (not)?

No. It will "work" for the immediate goal of getting your power on. That's unfortunate, because that tempts people to do it and create all the safety hazards discussed herein.

Comment: @jay613 there you go. Better?

Answer (score 3):

What you are talking about doing is using a device called a **suicide cord** to power the house through an outlet, without an interlock, rather than using an inlet to power the house with an interlock..

They are called suicide cords for the obvious reason. Don't do this. Do it right with an interlock, or plug things directly into the generator with no house wiring involved.

Your power provider may opt to disconnect your service such that your power outage will continue indefinitely, long after your neighbors' power is restored, for opting to do this improperly (creating a hazard for their employees.)

An interlock is a device that permits only one of two breakers to be on (both can be off). It is placed so that your main breaker from the power company is one of he two breakers, and the inlet you connect your generator to is the other. So, for the generator breaker to be on, the main breaker must be off, and for the main breaker to be on, the generator breaker must be off. It physically prevents you from backfeeding power to the grid. There are other ways to achieve the same end, - this is typically the least expensive method that is approved.

Comment: Thank you - I think you put it very clearly. Could I ask you to add what "interlock" means, please?

Comment: It means a device that blocks two things from happening at the same time, in this case it is designed so that in one position the main breaker *must* be off and in the other position that another breaker *must* be off, so that either both off or one on & one off, but never both on. I'll add a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Only way to do this is with an isolator switch so that backfeeding of the street cannot happen.

Check with qualified electricians as there are regulations about the detail - that is different in each country.

Comment: Isolator switch: Is this what Ecnerwal calls "interlock"?

Comment: Something that serves the same function, anyway. Might be more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

To just answer your questions: if that single 230 volt fed the entire house, then the entire house would have power. If the current exceeded the breaker rating of the outlet circuit, then that breaker would trip. If the main breaker was closed, then power would go out to the grid. If the main breaker was opened, then power would remain in the house and not go out to the grid.

I'm sure it's done in some areas and have actually seen it done here after hurricanes. If the power companies or any of the first responders find this, they will disconnect your service and you'll be the last one to get your service back on and then, only after getting an inspection and paying civil fines. It is extremely dangerous to everyone in the household to have a suicide cord. It is also very dangerous to the linemen working on the lines that are now backfed and to any neighbors that happen to come in contact with those lines.